# Magento2 how to upload images in image slider in the home page?

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm new to magento2, I've been trying to create a site of my own , I decided to download a free theme called "**Hidden-techies Next**" and configured it in my local system, the theme has an opening image slider in the home page, all I want is to add some images in the image slider, so I went to the block where the image was placed and found out that it was a "CMS block" called "**Home Slider**" and then i tried to edit the image in the slider and changed it to my onw images, here's the code below

```
<div class="home-slider-wrapper">
<div class="home-slider-main below-padding">
<ul class="home-slider">
<li><a href="#"><img class="image-responsive middle-block" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slider/next-home-banner-1.png"}}" alt="home banner"> </a></li>
<li style="display: none;"><a href="#"><img class="image-responsive middle-block" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/matt-artz-4mAcustUNPs-unsplash.jpg"}}" alt="home banner"> </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

But the issue i got in here is when I tried to change the image or add few more images in the slider the slider malfunctions, like the slider is no more a slider but its just few images arranged one below one and the , also if i try reverting my changes and saved them the slider malfunctions anyways, it remains the same without the next button , here's a image of my scenario
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyded.png
what I want in here is just to add some images into the slider, please help me out on my mistakes, idk what or where I did my mistakes, thanks for any reply's.

Answer (score 0):

Please Go to Admin -> Content -> Pages -> Edit you page.
After that in content tab please click on Show/Hide Editor and check there is some script code available or not if there not then maybe possible you removed slider script code.